# Wait method to complete and call another action in same controller in Entity Framework Core 7?

Tags: c#, sql-server, async-await, entity-framework-core

I have 2 methods in controller

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Department>>> GetDepartments()
{
     if (_dbcontext.Departments == null)
     {
         return NotFound();
     }
     else
     {
         return await _dbcontext.Departments.ToListAsync();
     }
}

[Route("SaveDepartments")]
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Department>>> SaveDepartments([FromBody] List<Department> departments)
{
     var tasks = new List<Task>();

     if (departments == null)
     {
         return NoContent();
     }
     else
     {
         foreach (var department in departments)
         {
             _dbcontext.Entry(department).State = department.ID == 0 ? EntityState.Added : EntityState.Modified;
         }

         \\ Here I am updating records in to database and calling action GetDepartments()
         await _dbcontext.SaveChangesAsync();

         var depts = await GetDepartments();

         return depts;
     }
}
```

In the above function, I am updating records in to database and calling action `GetDepartments()` to get latest data.

```
     await _dbcontext.SaveChangesAsync();
     var depts = await GetDepartments();
```

I have tried different approaches using `Task.When`, but I am getting request data, not latest data from database even I call `GetDepartments()` function.

Could anyone help me with this?

Thank you.

Comment: Where does `_dbcontext` get created? It should be a new one for each request.

Comment: Create a save method and wrap the save call the to dbContext in a lock block. Lock statements cannot be async, if you want it async, use a flag instead.

Comment: `ToListAsync` should always execute on the database. Verify that `SaveChangesAsync` is actually inserting rows by assigning its return value to a variable and inspecting it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is normal that EF would cache some of the data. As in, return data that was just put in.

If you want to bypass the entity cache, you can try to use .AsNoTracking() on the query:

```
return await _dbcontext.Departments.AsNoTracking().ToListAsync();
```

You should virtually never run Tasks of EF core concurrently, so I don't see the use of the task list.